# path of stylesheet not working php

Tags: php, path, stylesheet

im trying to link the stylesheet but for some reason I go to the page and its as if its not linked to the page (i.e. as if theres no stylesheet). This is the code for the page. Im new to this so i dont know if im giving enough information and nor can i think of anything else to put in. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

echo "
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
        <title>Home - Study Success</title>
        <!-- link to Styles -->
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href= \"$path/test/styles.css\">
    </head>
";

include_once ("$path/test/wrapper.php");
```

also if i view the source page, copy and paste the path of the stylesheet in a new tab, the stylesheet opens up but if i click and select open in new tab i get a blank page. Just opened it on firefox, viewed source page and clicked on the path of the stylesheet, this is what i got, i still have no idea how to fix this!?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /test/.C:/Program Files       (x86)/Apache/htdocs/test/styles.css
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: what do you expect for $path to print out? and whats the REAL path to the file

Comment: $path prints out C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\htdocs and the location of the file is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\htdocs\test, i have folders within htdocs and i want the sytles sheet to be accesible in whatever path the php file is in without changing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see what you mean, don't rely on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` that will look in the filesystem:

```
<?php
// this can go in a config file that you can include
define('CSS_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/css'));

echo '
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home - Study Success</title>
        <!-- link to Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="'.CSS_PATH.'/test/styles.css">
    </head>
';

include_once (CSS_PATH."/test/wrapper.php");
```

Now im not sure why you have `style.css` and `wrapper.php` in the same directory but in this example I assume you placed it in a directory called `css`.

So you might need to tweak this, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

The root of your web-server on the client side is the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` folder on the server side.

So you can just use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/styles.css">
```

(without including `$path`)

Comment: this would only work if `/test/` is at the same level as the page being served.

Comment: @Eeji No, with the starting slash `/` it is an absolute path, relative to the root of the web-server.

Comment: ah, my bad, I missed the slash. That will teach me not to skim read! :D

Comment: i need it to work regardless of the level of the page itself thanks though!

Comment: @user3408117 This will work regardless of the level of the page as it is an absolute path.

Comment: But if I move either the styles or the Web page and leave the other one where it is it won't work and that's what I'm trying to get to work thanks:)

Comment: Oh right OK thanks I was hoping for a way so I can upload it to the Web server without changing the path Thanks A Mill Though, Guess There Just isnt A Way To Do That?

Comment: @user3408117 You could probably set a configuration variable but I normally don't work with sites in sub-folders, I prefer to use virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives the root path on the server, not the URL. Try using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead